# Can I generate the difference between 2 texture seeds?

Tags: animation, texturing

I am making an animation with water. I am using textures for the water (of course). The problem is, I want the water to move. When I change offset or size etc. you can very clearly see it moving. When I try to get the difference between 2 seeds, it generates the seeds in between (ex. 1->2 becomes 1.1->1.2->1.3). What I want is that it takes 2 points (1->2) and then generate the difference between those points, not the seeds. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: maybe using shape keys

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking could you post some more info, maybe an example image of what you want, some screenshot of your scene or even the blender file itself? Are you using image bases textures or procedural textures? What 'seed' value are you talking about? How are you animating it?